# Saving multiple Excel Files to a Specific Path with Unique Filenames

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, save

In a loop I adjust the CSV structure of each file.

Now I want them to save in to the assigned folder with unique file names.

I can save to a CSV file, but than CSV file gets overwritten resulting in only the final modified result of the test5 file. I want save the CSV under their own `filename+string _modified` format.

I have 5 csv files:
Test1.csv
test2.csv
test3.csv
test4.csv
test5.csv

I import them:

```py
for x in allFiles:
    print(x)
    stop=1
    with open(x, 'r') as thecsv:
        base=os.path.basename(ROT)
        filename=os.path.splitext(base)[0]
        print(name)
```

Now I loop through the files manipulate them and save it as `DataFrame`.
This is working fine.

Now I want to save each file separately in the output folder with a unique name (filename + _modified)

Output='J:\Temp\Output'

This is what I tried:

```py
df2.to_csv(output+filename+'//_modified.csv'),sep=';',header=False,index=False)
```

also tried:

```py
df2.to_csv(output(os.path.join(name+'//_modified.csv'),sep=';',header=False,index=False)
```

Hoping for the output folder looks like this:

test1_modified.csv

test2_modified.csv

test3_modified.csv

test4_modified.csv

test5_modified.csv

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, making a new name before the call to write it out:

```
testFiles = ["test1.csv", "test2.csv", "test3.csv",
             "test4.csv", "test5.csv"]

# iterate over each one
for f in testFiles:
    # strip old extensions, replace with nothing
    f = f.replace(".csv", "")
    # I'd use join but you can you +
    newName = "_".join([f, "_modified.csv"])
    print(newName)
    # make your call to write it out
```

I would also check the pandas docs for writing out, it's simpler than what you're trying:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd 

# read data 
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
# write data to local
iris.to_csv("iris.csv")
```

Comment: thanks for your help It doesnt work for me.. I just want to save multiple csv files in an output location. each with an unique name

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? If you feed it real files it should work. You'' still need to open them with pandas and such. It you put the names of the files in the list you should be able to d it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem

df.to_csv(output+'\'+filename+'.csv',sep=';',header=False,index=False)